# Google Apps Script write fetched image files to Google Developer Storage, like a cache

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

I am not sure if this is possible, so I am looking for suggestions. Here is the scenario. Use GAS (Google Apps Script) to fetch image files from slow source and upload/write/post these files to somewhere else that is faster and more scaleable, like Google Developer Storage (GDS). Then serve the files to my web site from GDS rather than the source.

I assume to use UrlFetchApp.fetch(url) to get the image, and getContent() to get the file, but I can't find how to send/post/write the file to a server/storage?

While looking through the docs, I noticed "Cache Services". Maybe this is what I am looking for. But it appears to be for internal use, not to feed the cached data via a URL to a web site.
I also noticed that the JDBC service allows you to write to a database, so I could store the image files in a database, but that seems overkill just to cache and re-serve static images.

Cheers

Comment: The [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_cacheservice) is not a solution for your case because the cache size is quite limited. Its size is maximum a few megabytes. Also it stores only strings, i.e. it is necessary to encode the images using the Base64 or something like that (Cached string data size is increased relatively to binary representation).  As result only small amount of images can be cached.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think the Cache Service was the solution, but it needed to be clarified. Can GAS not POST or Write to a Server?  I know you can write to GAS and get responses.

Would this task best be handled by Google App Engine, if so, can anyone offer some code ( as I am not a GAE user?)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Google Site, with a file container page, then upload the images to that container.  There is a call to retrieve the url once the image has been uploaded. By making the site public, you can host images and use them from other interfaces. Here's a snippet of code that does that:

```
  var file = your_blob; // this should be the content of the image
  var err = 0;
  var errText = '';
  var picUrl = '';

  // Uploads the image to the sites container page
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl('https://sites.google.com/a/yourdomain.com/yourpage');

  try {
    var attachment = page.addHostedAttachment(file);
    picUrl = attachment.getUrl();
  } catch (e) {
    err = 1;
    errText = e;
  }

  // picUrl now contains the url for the image..
```

Hope this helps. 
Chris